# CSS grid-template-area stretching problem

Tags: css, css-grid

I have made a calculator. To align buttons, I have used grid-template-area and grid-area. It is supposed to stretch equal button vertically, however, it does not work. I check from inspector by using overlay grid and display area names, and It looks like there is no problem, but there is a problem. How can I stretch equal area vertically?

Thank you for taking the time.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.calculator {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.panel {
  background-color: olive;
  color: white;
  width: 16.25rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  text-align: end;
}

.buttons {
  display: grid;
  background-color: pink;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-template-areas: ". . . ." "seven eight nine equal" "four five six equal" "one two three equal" "clear zero dot equal";
}

[data-type="number"]:active,
[data-type="operator"]:active {
  background-color: gray;
}

.buttons>button {
  border: none;
  height: 6vh;
}

.zero {
  grid-area: zero;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
}

.seven {
  grid-area: seven;
}

.eight {
  grid-area: eight;
}

.nine {
  grid-area: nine;
}

.equal {
  grid-area: equal;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.clean {
  grid-area: clear;
}

.dot {
  grid-area: dot;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="panel">0</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button data-process="minus" data-type="operator">-</button>
      <button data-process="add" data-type="operator">+</button>
      <button data-process="multiply" data-type="operator">&times;</button>
      <button data-process="divide" data-type="operator">&divide;</button>
      <button class="zero" data-type="number">0</button>
      <button class="one" data-type="number">1</button>
      <button class="two" data-type="number">2</button>
      <button class="three" data-type="number">3</button>
      <button class="four" data-type="number">4</button>
      <button class="five" data-type="number">5</button>
      <button class="six" data-type="number">6</button>
      <button class="seven" data-type="number">7</button>
      <button class="eight" data-type="number">8</button>
      <button class="nine" data-type="number">9</button>
      <button class="clean" data-type="clean">C</button>
      <button class="dot" data-type="number">.</button>
      <button class="equal" data-type="equal">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the html code as well

Comment: Please add the html code so that we can help you.

Comment: I've added html codes as well

Comment: If the problem has been solved then don't edit the word "Solved" into the question. Instead [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (unless the problem was trivial (such as a typo or not running the version of the code you shared) in which case you should delete the question instead). You can write your own answer if you solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was with height value fixed on it.
remove or alter

```
 .buttons>button {
     height: 6vh;
    }
```

```css
   

 * {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html {
      font-size: 150%;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: cadetblue;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .calculator {
      box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .panel {
      background-color: olive;
      color: white;
      width: 16.25rem;
      padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
      text-align: end;
    }
    
    .buttons {
      display: grid;
      background-color: pink;
      grid-gap: 1px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
      grid-template-areas: ". . . ." "seven eight nine equal" "four five six equal" "one two three equal" "clear zero dot equal";
    }
    
    [data-type="number"]:active,
    [data-type="operator"]:active {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    
    .buttons>button {
      border: none;
    }
    
    .zero {
      grid-area: zero;
    }
    
    .one {
      grid-area: one;
    }
    
    .two {
      grid-area: two;
    }
    
    .three {
      grid-area: three;
    }
    
    .four {
      grid-area: four;
    }
    
    .five {
      grid-area: five;
    }
    
    .six {
      grid-area: six;
    }
    
    .seven {
      grid-area: seven;
    }
    
    .eight {
      grid-area: eight;
    }
    
    .nine {
      grid-area: nine;
    }
    
    .equal {
      grid-area: equal;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .clean {
      grid-area: clear;
    }
    
    .dot {
      grid-area: dot;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="panel">0</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button data-process="minus" data-type="operator">-</button>
      <button data-process="add" data-type="operator">+</button>
      <button data-process="multiply" data-type="operator">&times;</button>
      <button data-process="divide" data-type="operator">&divide;</button>
      <button class="zero" data-type="number">0</button>
      <button class="one" data-type="number">1</button>
      <button class="two" data-type="number">2</button>
      <button class="three" data-type="number">3</button>
      <button class="four" data-type="number">4</button>
      <button class="five" data-type="number">5</button>
      <button class="six" data-type="number">6</button>
      <button class="seven" data-type="number">7</button>
      <button class="eight" data-type="number">8</button>
      <button class="nine" data-type="number">9</button>
      <button class="clean" data-type="clean">C</button>
      <button class="dot" data-type="number">.</button>
      <button class="equal" data-type="equal">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```